# GridView is not visible on page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to fill a Gridview with data from a database view. I cant use linq because the view has 200+k rows i have to show. here is my code:

```
     public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string mobileGateway = "MobileGateway";
    private List<string> addressReport = new List<string>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetReport(addressReport);
    }

    public void GetReport(List<string> adr)
    {
        string connecntionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[mobileGateway].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connecntionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                string sqlCmd = "SELECT * from dbo.BarcodeWithLocation";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd, connection))
                {
                    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            adr.Add("" + reader[0]);
                            adr.Add("" + reader[1]);
                            adr.Add("" + reader[2]);
                            adr.Add("" + reader[3]);
                            adr.Add("" + reader[4]);
                            adr.Add("" + reader[5]);
                            adr.Add("" + reader[6]);
                            adr.Add("" + reader[7]);
                            adr.Add("" + reader[8]);
                            adr.Add("" + reader[9]);
                            adr.Add("" + reader[10]);
                        }

                        Grid.DataSource = adr;
                        Grid.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR!!!!: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

aspx code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="AddressReporting._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:GridView ID="Grid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
</asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

I get a blank page with no gridview at all. what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you post also the aspx page? And, btw, that try&catch's block is completely useless there

Comment: I would use a more secure methods for the `reader` class.
Instead using only the index, you should use GetString(index)/GetInt32(index)/...(based on the type you are reading). So your code should be: `reader.GetString(0)`. [This is a good reference link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: ill try, but dont think this would resolve my issue

Comment: Are you caching the layout, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

```
enter code here

command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
Grid.DataSource = reader;
Grid.DataBind();
```

try this it will get all the details into reader and bind it to grid directly. No need to loop through all the rows unless you want to do something else there.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but this would only opyimize my code and not solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
string sqlCmd = "SELECT * from dbo.BarcodeWithLocation";
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCmd, connection))
{
     DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
     command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
     connection.Open();
     SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

     dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

     Grid.DataSource = dataTable;
     Grid.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you query is fetching data or not  as you can't see empty GridView

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring ref

```
public void GetReport(ref List<string> adr)
```

[ref (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)